# Insert SVG into Word Document Using OpenXML

Tags: svg, openxml

I am trying to insert SVG into a Word document using DocumentFormat.OpenXML. I was hoping it would be something simple like this:

```
string svg="<svg string goes here>";
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip pic = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip(svg);
```

I get an error stating that the XML can't be processed, so the Blip constructor must be looking for something other than an svg string. I'm not even sure that the Blip class is what I need to use.

If you have a straightforward example of how to do this, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: _Dear Google, what is a BLIP class?_ Answer: **Binary** Large Image or Picture

Comment: Well it was obviously wrong, that's why I'm here. My hope is that someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I would use the GUI and insert an SVG. Then save and unzip the docx structure and find document.xml and see how it is inserted. Then you should be able to get closer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kevin. That's actually the first thing I did and it doesn't appear to be straightforward at all. It looks as though the GUI decomposes the svg into all its instructions -- or at least the ones it supports.

Comment: I thought I had read somewhere that the SVG schema was going to be added to the OpenXML SDK. Couldn't find it though. In the mean time, this may be what you're looking for: https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/add-svg-to-document-t2927.html